# Dropdownlistfor will not show the correct selection

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have three dropdownlistfor in a loop that do not show the correct value from the DB.  They always default to the first entry.  I have checked and double checked the DB and verified that it should be the second one in the list.  The list is also created correctly.  What am I missing?

```
        @foreach (CustomerMeasurementProfile oProfile in Model.Customer.CustomerMeasurementProfiles.Where(m => m.DeletedDate == null))
        {

            <div class="valuesforoneprofile form-group form-group-tight col-md-2">
                <div class="col-md-11" >
                    @Html.Hidden(string.Format("Customer.CustomerMeasurementProfiles[{0}].Id", i), oProfile.Id)
                    @Html.Hidden(string.Format("Customer.CustomerMeasurementProfiles[{0}].CustomerId", i), oProfile.CustomerId)
                    @Html.TextBox(string.Format("Customer.CustomerMeasurementProfiles[{0}].Name", i), oProfile.Name, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11" style="text-align:center">
                    @Html.CheckBox(string.Format("DeleteProfiles[{0}]", i), Model.DeleteProfiles[i])
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-top:4px;">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => oProfile.BodyTypeShoulderId, new SelectList(Model.BodyTypeShoulders, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control input-sm-select" }) 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-top:4px;">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => oProfile.BodyTypePostureId, new SelectList(Model.BodyTypePosture, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control input-sm-select" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-top:4px;">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => oProfile.BodyTypeChestId, new SelectList(Model.BodyTypeChest, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control input-sm-select" }) 
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the selected value that is coming in **Model**. You need to do it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => oProfile.BodyTypeShoulderId, 
                           new SelectList(Model.BodyTypeShoulders, 
                                          "Id", 
                                          "Name",
                                          oProfile.BodyTypeShoulderId), 
                           new { @class = "form-control input-sm-select" })
```

The above code will set the dropdown selected value to whatever is in the current **Model** object `BodyTypeShoulderId`

The first argument of `DropDownListFor` tells that on form post drop down selected value will be mapped with the Model property which is set there (we are passing `m => oProfile.BodyTypeShoulderId`) but this not sets selected Value.

For setting selected value you have to pass `SelectList` fourth parameter using [this overload of SelectList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725507%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which is `object selectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `@Html.DropDownListFor()` behaves a little differently than other helpers when rendering controls in a loop. For a single object

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => oProfile.BodyTypeShoulderId, new SelectList(Model.BodyTypeShoulders, "Id", "Name"))
```

would work fine (if the value of `BodyTypeShoulderId` matches the value of one of the options, then that option would be selected). Ehsan has shown a work around when using it in a loop, however you have a few other issues in you code, not the least is that many of your properties will not post back correctly to a collection because your using a `foreach` loop rather than a `for` loop (which is generating duplicate `name` and `id` attributes). Your also generating a new `SelectList` in each iteration of the loop which is not very efficient.

You can solve both these and the dropdown selection issue by using an `EditorTemplate`. Assuming property `CustomerMeasurementProfiles` is typeof `CustomerMeasurementProfiles`, then

CustomerMeasurementProfiles.cshtml (add this to `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` or `Views/YourController/EditorTemplates`)

```
@model CustomerMeasurementProfiles
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerId)
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BodyTypeShoulderId, (SelectList)ViewData["shoulders"])
....
```

In the view model, add properties for the `SelectList`'s and filtered collection of the items to display

```
IEnumerable<CustomerMeasurementProfiles> ActiveCustomerMeasurementProfiles { get; set; }
public SelectList BodyTypeShoulderList { get; set; }
....
```

and assign those values in the controller

Then in the main view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ...
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActiveCustomerMeasurementProfiles, new { shoulders = Model.BodyTypeShoulderList })
  ...
```

Using `@Html.EditorFor()` with a collection will correctly name the controls (and correctly select the right options) and on post back, `ActiveCustomerMeasurementProfiles` will now be correctly populated with all its properties.