# Selected Dropdown using HTML Helpers in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to select the dropdown in html helper. I pass my data in IEnumerable using ViewData please some one help me how to select it with value.

My Code is

```
@Html.DropDownList("Brand", ViewData["Brand"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, item.BrandMaster, new { @class = "form-control Repeat TableMust"})
```

Here

1. `ViewData["Brand"]` is my Dropdown list.
2. I want to select `item.BrandMaster` value in dropdown.

But the problem is it's showing the text but it does not contain the value. The value is "" empty, how to select it in html helpers?

Comment: This should do @Html.DropDownList("Brand", 
    new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable) ViewData["Brand"], "Id", "Name"))

Comment: what is id and what is name

Comment: id could be your value and Name could be your Text. Say Brand table has BrandID  and BrandName the ID =BrandID and Text = BrandName

Comment: @Vivekh, This does not bind to property `BrandMaster`

Comment: Yes, its not working

Comment: Ya My Bad Didnt got the whole point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ViewData["Brand"]` contains an object `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, I guess you have already used its constructor or more likely Object Initializer, e.g.:

```
List<SelectListItem> brand = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
   new { Value = 1 , Text = "something 1"  },
   new { Value = 2 , Text = "something 2"  },
   new { Value = 3 , Text = "something 3"  },
};
ViewData["Brand"] = brand;
```

In your View, you use the list as a second parameter for `DropDownList` helper. You also need to provide what its Value and Text. The last parameter indicates which value is to be selected by default:

```
@Html.DopDownList("Brand",
    (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Brand"],
    "value", "text", 2)
```

You could also try `SelectList` container to "fill" the `DropDownList` helper. Simply send your list of Objects to view in ViewData etc., and use it as a second parameter. Then provide Value and Text as the third and the fourth parameters, respectively. The last parameter corresponds to the value of your selected item in the list.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Brand", new SelectList(
    Model.ListOfYourObjects,
    "<<< Property name as value in the Object, e.g. ID",
    "<<< Property name as text in the Object, e.g. Name/Title/etc.",
    <<< value of thecurrent ID >>>));
```

e.g.

```
public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
ViewData["Cities"] = dbContext.Cities.ToList();
//or
ViewData["Cities"] = new List<City>(); // fill this list
```

In a view:

```
@model List<City>
// ...
@Html.DropDownList(
    "Brand",
    new SelectList(
        Model, "ID", "Name",
        <<< value of ID to be selected or null>>>
    )
);
```

`ID` and `Name` are property names in the class `City` which is important here in order for `SelectList` to work.

I couldn't try this code but this should give you something to work with. Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

If the property your binding to is named `BrandMaster` then it should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BrandMaster, ViewData["Brand"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control Repeat TableMust"})
```

If the value of `BrandMaster` matches the value of one of the SelectList items, then it will be selected by default.

Always use the strongly types helpers!

**Edit**

To use create a dropdown for the property of a collection, you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int BrandMaster { get; set; }
  public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

MyModel.cshtml (in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`

```
@model MyModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BrandMaster, ViewData["Brand"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control Repeat TableMust"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnotherProperty)
```

Main View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { Brand = ViewData["Brand"])
  ....
}
```

Comment: No i don't want to select default value i want to select item.BrandMaster Value

Comment: That what it will do! Read my answer

Comment: if it is IEnumberable<model> then how to select it

Comment: Then you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate`. I'll update answer shortly (you would never have been able to post back your collection with the code in your question anyway)

Comment: @Dinesh, Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742155/dropdownlistfor-will-not-show-the-correct-selection/26752086#26752086) for a more detailed explanation on using `DropDownListFor()` in a collection

Comment: If this answer isn't working, something is definitely wrong with your `ViewData`

Answer (score 0):

When you are building your dropdown list you can select the selected item using `Selected` property of SelectListItem

```
myModelCollection = SomeService.GetModels();
var dropdown = myModelCollection.Select(s => new SelectListItem {Value = s.Id, Name = s.Name, Selected = s.Id == YourSelectedValue} ).ToList();
```