# Dropdown list from table in ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get dropdown list with values from table. I'm have model:

```
namespace MobileService.Models
{
    public class Mobile
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Model { get; set;}

            Public string EMEI { get; set ;}

            public int MasterId { get; set; }

            public List<Master> MasterList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Master
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

In controller I creat action for this model:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In view:

```
@model MobileService.Models.Mobile
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model)
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EMEI )
 // And here i want to display a dropdown list with all available masters

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Creat</button>
}
```

But it always tell me that Model.MasterList is null . But why? In model i told to get list from another model (**public List MasterList { get; set; }**). Why is it null?

Comment: Show us the controller code where you suppose to load your model..

Comment: [C# MVC get values from dropdownlist](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23%20MVC%20get%20values%20from%20dropdownlist) amazing what a Simple `GOOGLE SEARCH` can `Yield`

Comment: *Model.MasterList is null . But why?* - what makes you think it wouldn't be?

Comment: Try [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955447/selected-dropdown-using-html-helpers-in-mvc-4?answertab=active#tab-top). There's an explanation on how to create `DropDownList`.

Comment: _But it always tell me that Model.MasterList is null_

Currently, based on your code, you are not returning anything to View: `return View() // it's EMPTY`. Therefore, your model is null, even though the View expects `Mobile`. Later, look for `SelectList` and `DropDownList`. SelectList can be tricky but once you have understood it, It's easy to create `DropDonwList`, or even better `DropFownListFor`

Answer (score 0):

This code is in VB. In the beginning even i looked for a lot of time this is the simple solution i found.

Convert the model into list of selectListItems

```
Dim lstEmpTypes As New List(Of SelectListItem)



lstTicketWrTypes.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = row("Something"), .Value = row("Something")})
```

'Then load it into a ViewBag

```
ViewBag.EmpTypes = lstEmpTypes
```

'And in you View

```
                 @Html.DropDownList("selectWrType", New SelectList(ViewBag.EmpTypes , "Value", "Text"), New With {.class = "span3"})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you query for Mobile you need to Include("MasterList"), or turn lazy loading on on your context (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to add this to controller:

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {    
     ViewBag.MasterId = new SelectList(db.Masters, "Id", "Name");
     return View();
    }
```

Then in view to show droplist:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("MasterId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Thnx  **ZikO** who let me now that list didn't loaded automatical.