# Unable to bind selectlistitem to model property

Tags: c#, razor, selectlistitem

I have a couple of classes like below -

```
public class P
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PDetail> PDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my View, I am displaying it as -

```
@foreach (var detail in Model.PDetails)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => detail.Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Types"], "--Type--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => detail.Price, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Price" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here, I am able to display `detail.Price` for each detail object, but `detail.Type` is not getting selected from `ViewData["Types"]` dropdownlist.

PS: `ViewData["Types"]` is just a dictionary of typeIds = {1,2,3...}

### Info1

I also tried changing the View to -

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PDetails.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PDetails.ElementAt(i).Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Types"], "--Type--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But it is still not working. How can I go about fixing it?

Comment: _"ViewData["Types"]" is just a dictionary of typeIds = {1,2,3,...}"_ That doesn't look like a dictionary... Dictionaries have keys and values, and they can't be cast to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Can you tell us what `ViewData["Types"]` actually is?

Comment: It is something like this - 
ViewData["Types"] = new SelectList(formats, "Id", "Name", null);

Comment: Ok, and what is `formats`?

Comment: var formats = from Constants.Type f in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Constants.Type))
                          select new { Id = (int)f, Name = f.ToString() };

Comment: Constants.Type is just an enum of strings which are to be selected by user.

Comment: Thanks. Well, that all looks ok. Does the dropdown correctly show the list of available values? If you view the HTML source, does it show the values paired with their numbers? If you use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => detail.Type)` does it show the expected number?

Comment: Dropdown is showing correct values. I am even able to select one and save it. But when I fetch the value from DB and try to display, then it doesn't get selected. And yes, I am able to see the correct value on @Html.TextBoxFor(m => detail.Type)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DropDownListFor not binding on Edit View with repeating items (List<T>)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501498/dropdownlistfor-not-binding-on-edit-view-with-repeating-items-listt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sticking through my barrage of questions. I was able to reproduce your issue, and after a whole lot of attempts to get it to work, it seems that this may just be a bug in the MVC framework that hasn't been fixed in over 4 years.

This answer provides two workarounds:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3529347/1945651

One involves using a somewhat verbose bit of code to manually add the value to the ModelState.

The other requires your list of items to be indexable with square brackets (e.g. an array or `IList`/`IList<T>`), and then involves adding the current value as a default value in the `SelectList` passed to the HTML helper:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PDetails.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PDetails[i].Type, 
                                 new SelectList(ViewData["Types"] as IEnumerable, 
                                            "Value", "Text", Model.PDetails[i].Text), 
                                 "--Type--", 
                                 htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Could you give that a try?

Comment: Acc to my code it should look like this right - new SelectList(ViewData["Types"] as IEnumerable,                                                "Id", "Name", Model.PDetails[i].Type) ?

Comment: I changed it like you said and it is working fine now! Thanks a lot. I also found that it works with ICollection too. The list of items does not need to be indexable.

Comment: Another (I think better option because you do not have to generate a new `SelectList` with each iteration) is to use an `EditorTemplate` [as per this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955447/selected-dropdown-using-html-helpers-in-mvc-4/26955475#26955475).