# Bootstrap tabs + Dropdown selected item based on model value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a (probably simple) problem.
I have a really hard time explaining what exactly I'm trying to do.

I have a page looping through a list of items and creating a new tab for each item. 
Im using Bootstrap tabs
(**this works**)
I know this is horrible MVC -> but im fairly new to web development - which is why i feel like im in the deep end of the pool atm.

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#@item.EndDate.ToString("M").Replace(" ", "")" aria-controls="@item.EndDate.ToString("M").Replace(" ", "")" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">@item.EndDate.ToString("d")</a>
            </li>
        }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <div class="tab-content col-md-10">

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <div role="tab-pane" class="tab-pane" id="@item.EndDate.ToString("M").Replace(" ", "")">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(mx => item.Assignment)
                    </div>
                   etc...
```

In each tab, I have some textboxes and some other stuff AND a dropdownlist which basically is a selector for something else. the Dropdown looks like below.

```
<div>
   @{
        var listItems = new List<ListItem> { new ListItem { Text = "Calendar", Value = "Calendar" }, new ListItem { Text = "Email", Value = "Email" } };
    }
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.Type, new SelectList(listItems), "-- Select Type --", new { @id = item.ItemId +"_TypeSelector", @class="TypeSelector" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => item.Type)
</div>
```

**My problem;**

The dropdown does not select the correct value based on the model value.

thanks in advance..

Comment: Actually it won't work at all. You `foreach` loop is creating duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes so nothing will be bound to your collection when you post back anyway. Because your creating a drop down you will need to create a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742155/dropdownlistfor-will-not-show-the-correct-selection/26752086#26752086)

Comment: Om actually giving everything unique ids by adding The item id with a string, so all ids are infact unique

Comment: OK, missed that, but they have the same names so they wont post back to a collection. Using the `EditorTemplate` as per the link will not only name them correctly with indexers but also give them unique id's (so no need to add this using the html attributes) and select the correct option based on on the value of property `Type`

Comment: I also have some javascript that checks the "changed" event - will this work with this solution - checking each different dropdown if they have the same class?

Comment: `$('.TypeSelector').change(function() { var value = $(this).val(); .. });` will work fine

Comment: Great - thank you very much. I will try it out when I have time - I'll mark your answer as solution if you post one. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering you collection in a `foreach` loop as you are doing will give your controls duplicate names and therefore you will not be able to post back and bind to the collection. Your can handle this correctly by using a `for` loop or using a custom `EditorTemplate`. Unfortunately `@Html.DropDownListFor()` does not work correctly for server to view binding in a loop ([refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742155/dropdownlistfor-will-not-show-the-correct-selection/26752086#26752086)), so in your case, you need to use an `EditorTemplate`

The way you are generating your options also does not make much sense and means you are creating a new `SelectList` with each iteration. This should be created in the controller and passed as a property in your view model or via `ViewBag` as follows

```
List<string> items = new List<string>(){ "Calendar", "Email" };
ViewBag.ItemList = new SelectList(items);
```

Assuming property `Items` is typeof `Item` which contains property `Type` then, create an `EditorTemplate` in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`

Item.cshtml

```
@model Item
<div role="tab-pane" class="tab-pane">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, (SelectList)ViewData["ItemList"]), "- Select Type -", new { @class="TypeSelector" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Type)
    </div>
    // other properties of Item as required
  <div>
</div>
```

and in the main view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div class="tab-content col-md-10">
    @EditorFor(m => m.Items, new { ItemList = ViewBag.ItemList })
  </div>
}
```

This passes the `SelectList` to the `EditorTemplate` and will render a `<select>` for each `Item` which are correctly named and can be bound on post back.

```
<select name="Items[0].Type" id="Items_0__Type" class="typeselector">
<select name="Items[1].Type" id="Items_1__Type" class="typeselector">
```

If the value of property `Type` is `"Calendar"`, then the second option will be selected in the view; if its `"Email"`, then the third option will be selected; otherwise the first (label) option will be selected.

Comment: It's not working, its not giving me Unique Id's and the dropdown is showing as a textbox. could this be because im using a nested class?
In my controller im getting a list of ItemA, each ItemA includes a List of ItemB -> the editortemplate is for ItemB - My Classes are not added by the way

Comment: Of course it giving you unique id's (duplicate id's are invalid html!). If its giving you a textbox, its not finding the `EditorTemplate`. Did you name it correctly (see 3rd paragraph of my answer - you haven't post the model so I guessed `Model.Items` is a collection of a class name `Item`)

Comment: so do i still use my foreach(var item in model)?

Comment: No. In fact if you use a loop, `EditorFor()` will not work correctly.

Comment: So how do i loop through all of my items and show them as different tabs? right now i create a tab each time a go through an item - which is why ive been using the foreach - I mean if i dont use the loop how would the code know to spawn multiple tabs?

Comment: If a property is a collection, then `@Html.EditorFor()` internally does a loop and creates the controls for each item in the collection. The code in you question does not show how your creating tabs. How are you doing this? Are you using a jquery plugin?

Comment: You can put `<div role="tab-pane" class="tab-pane"  ...>` in the EditorTemplate (I don't use Bootstrap, but I assume that `class="tab-pane"` results in the creation of tabs.). I'll edit answer to include this. And do you really need to add an `id` to the `div`?

Comment: yeah because the tab references the id of the taskpane - Oh that is great - ill try it out :) thanks - im getting The ViewData item that has the key 'Type' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. on the editortemplate btw

Comment: That error would be because your passing either `null`, or a  `string` to the dropdown list, not a `SelectList`. Have you done it as per the first code block in my answer? `ViewBag.ItemList = new SelectList(items);` It might also happen if you post then return the view but have not reassigned the `ViewBag` property.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out and everything is fine now