# Dropdownlistfor selected item not selecting using viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, dropdownlistfor

I have dropdownlistfor which is getting populated from viewbag string array

```
 <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].start_operation, new SelectList(ViewBag.ValidOpers))</td>
 <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].end_operation, new SelectList(ViewBag.ValidOpers))</td>
```

It is not selecting the selected item based on Model[i].start_operation and end_operation

```
ViewBag.ValidOpers = new[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
```

Unable to figure out why it is not selecting. I check giving just a `Html.DisplayFor(m=>Model[i].start_operation` to check if it is getting the values and yes it is getting the value and displaying correctly in the label, but the same value is not getting selected in the dropdownlistfor.

Comment: This is bug with using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` in a `for` loop. Instead you need to use a a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model. [Refer this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962981/bootstrap-tabs-dropdown-selected-item-based-on-model-value/26985113#26985113)

Answer (score 1):

To over-answer your question:

Try first adding a not-mapped member to your model class:

e.g.

```
   [NotMapped]
   static public List<SelectListItem> myListOptions { get; set; }
```

then in the controller you can have

```
MyNameSpace.Models.MyModel.myListOptions = db.myTable.Select(uA=> new SelectListItem{ Value = uA.myColumn, Text = uA.myColumn}).Distinct().OrderBy(uA=>uA.Text).ToList();

// if you want string constants use:

        MyNameSpace.Models.MyModel.myListOptions  = new List<SelectListItem>();

        MyNameSpace.Models.MyModel.myListOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text = "a", Value = "a"});
        MyNameSpace.Models.MyModel.myListOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text = "b", Value = "b" });
```

then in the view, you use:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.myField, MyNameSpace.Models.MyModel.myListOptions )
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.myField)
    </div>
```

Comment: The original code I had worked for the db-load case but not the string  constant case, which is actually more complicated, the above should work now, at least in VS 2013

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, really aprpeciate . I tried part of your solution, it was still not showing the selected item. So what I did was change it to @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model[i].operatorToken, 
new SelectList(ViewBag.operatorTokensList, "Value", "Text", Model[i].operatorToken), 
"Select"). This worked and it shows the selected value during get as well as post.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Hopefully this will help someone else as well
!