# TwitterBootStrapMVC Dropdownlist Selected Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html.dropdownlistfor

I can't get the selected values from the following dropdownlist, here how I generate the list:

In the repository:

```
   public IQueryable<OhaType> GetAllOhaTypes ()
    { return db.OhaType.OrderBy(d => d.Name); }
```

In the controller:

```
....
  var OhTypes = _medicationRepository.GetAllOhaTypes();
  ViewBag.OhTypes = new SelectList(OhTypes, "OhaTypeId", "Name");
.....
```

In the View:

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.OhaMedication)
{
<tr>
<td>
@(Html.Bootstrap().DropDownList("OhaTypeId", (SelectList)ViewBag.OhTypes)
.HtmlAttributes(new
{
    Name ="OhaTypeId",
    style = "width: 300px;"
}).Size(InputSize.Small)
.Class("form-group input-sm").Id("OhaTypeId")
.ShowValidationMessage(true))
</td>
.....
```

I get the first item of the list displayed not the correct value.  I get the correct values in other fields from the table.

I also tried "@HTML.DropdownList(...)", same issue.

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: The control name `OhaTypeId` shouldn't be same for all lists

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  I am just using OhaTypeId once.

Comment: With `foreach`, DDL will be generated in all table rows. According to your code all DDLs will have same ID and  Name `OhaTypeId`, that causes the issue to not getting selected value. While Form Serialization It will consider only one list value. To solve your issue you need to use Display Or Editor template for row generation by supplying appropriate Model.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742155/dropdownlistfor-will-not-show-the-correct-selection/26752086#26752086) might help explain why you need to use an `EditorTemplate` when using `DropDownListFor` in a loop

Comment: Thank you both very helpful.  I used Editor template.