# Populating Multiple Dropdownlist with Edited value from database in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Generating number of Dropdownlists with Edited value from the database , **Dropdownlist is 
populating** , but not with the **Edited Value** . I am creating DropdownList based on No of Element in the List. below is Code sample------

```
@for (int a = 0; a < noofoption; a++)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SameOptionList[a].qopanswer(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.option, "--Select--")
```

SameOptionList is a List Type property. And If i am not using List its working fine.

List is Populating but not with Selected Value. Plz do Needful.

Answer (score 1):

When using `@Html.DropDownListFor` in a collection you need to use an `EditorTemplate`. A more detailed explanation is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742155/dropdownlistfor-will-not-show-the-correct-selection/26752086#26752086)

Comment: Thanks  Stephen Muecke :)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider accepting this (and all the other answers to your questions that have worked for you)