# Why don't the items from my dropdownlists in mvc get marked as selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using SelectLists to populate the following DropDownLists from the respective models.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Companies", Model.Companies)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role, "User Role")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Roles", Model.Roles)
</div>
```

Here's how it's populated:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetCompaniesList(List<Company> Companies)
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (Company comp in Companies)
    {
        var item = new SelectListItem { Text = comp.Companyname, Value = Convert.ToString(comp.PKey) };
        list.Add(item);
    }

    return list;
}
```

I'm simply adding this to the model by calling `model.CompaniesList = GetCompaniesList(CompanyModel.GetCompanies())`.

These lists render markup that looks like this:

```
<select id="ddlRoles" name="ddlRoles" class="valid">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Please select a Role</option>
    <option value="2">Admin</option>
    <option value="1">Master</option>
    <option value="3">User</option>
</select>
```

I manually wrote in the default value which is pre-selected.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the selected flag to move over to whichever item I'm selecting. As such, when it comes time to post to the controller, the selected values for these fields come up empty and throw an exception.

How can I get the dropdownlists to accept my selection and send the data along with the rest of the form in the ajax post?

**EDIT**

Here's my [HttpPost] Add ActionResult (it's a bit of a mess, but that's just some nasty data design on my part which I'll fix up later...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(UserModel model)
{
  // this check fails saying that Companies and Roles don't have values
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    try
    {
      // these fields are for auditing
      model.CreatedBy = String.Format("{0} {1}", Convert.ToString(Session["firstname"]), Convert.ToString(Session["lastname"]));
      model.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
      // get the selected values from the dropdownlists
      Int64 companyid = Convert.ToInt64(model.Companies.Single(x => x.Selected).Value);
      Int64 role = Convert.ToInt64(model.Roles.Single(x => x.Selected).Value);   
      // the UserModel accepts a User object to add to the database,
      // so copy the model's values over to the user object for adding.
      // this is a lot of the mess which will be cleaned up later
      User u = new User();
      WebCompany c = new WebCompany();
      WebRole r = new WebRole();
      u.Company = c.GetCompanyById(companyid);
      u.Role = r.GetRoleById(role);
      u.CreatedBy = model.CreatedBy;
      u.CreatedOn = model.CreatedOn;
      u.EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress;
      u.FirstName = model.FirstName;
      u.LastName = model.LastName;
      u.LastLogin = model.LastLogin;
      u.Password = model.Password;
      model.Add(u);
      return Json(new
      {
        Message = "Success",
        IsOK = bool.TrueString
      });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      {
        return ThrowError(ex, "Add");
      }
      else
      {
        return View("Index");
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // return a Json that contains information about why the model is invalid
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's the Model. A fair amount of inheritance is used here to provide common user values (email address, password) from a framework I'm writing.

*NOTE:* Until I tried to implement the dropdownlists, this all worked just fine.

`UserModel`: Provides MVC with access to the User object and includes CRUD functions

```
public class UserModel : User
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

    // CRUDs go here
}
```

`User`: Provide application-specific fields (companies, roles)

```
public class User : BaseUser
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

`BaseUser`: Provides user-common fields (email address, password)

```
public abstract class BaseUser : BaseObject
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public BaseUser()
    {
        EmailAddress = String.Empty;
        Password = String.Empty;
        FirstName = String.Empty;
        LastName = String.Empty;
    }        
}
```

`BaseObject`: Provides globally common fields to the database tables (primary key, auditing)

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 PKey { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public BaseObject()
    {
        CreatedBy = "System";
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;

        ModifiedBy = "System";
        ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<option selected="selected">` is just the default selection - i.e. when the view is rendered. (it does not change just because you select another item). To get the current selected value in jquery, use `$('#ddlRoles').val();`

Comment: mkay but how do I communicate which item was selected by the user to the controller?

Comment: You need to post the signature for the method you posting to and the ajax code your using to post (you don't appear to be binding to any model properties so hard to be sure what your doing)

Comment: Well I saw somewhere that changing the names of the `<select>`s would help with the selection issue but it didn't... These map to `List<SelectListItem>` properties in the model.

Comment: Changing the name of a select only ensure that binding will fail. You should also post the model as well.

Comment: My Add ActionResult for the POST accepts a UserModel object so yes, I'm posting the model, but it keeps failing at `if (!Model.IsValid)` saying that the Companies and Roles fields need to have values... even though I've already selected values for them

Comment: You don't bind to your `Companies` and `Roles` properties so how would you expect them to post back? (all your creating is controls named `ddlCompanies` and `ddlRoles` which have no relationship to your mode)l. Learn to use strongly type html helpers -`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YourProperty, Model.YourSelectList, "-Please select-")` - and you will never have this problem.

Comment: check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742155/dropdownlistfor-will-not-show-the-correct-selection

Comment: @StephenMuecke the values in the model I want to fill with the selection from the lists are `Company` and `Role` respectively... thus I've changed the dropdownlists to `@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.Company, Model.Companies, "-Please select a company-")` and now rather than telling me **Companies and Roles* don't have values, it's telling me **Company and Role** (singluar as per model values, not the lists) don't have values

Comment: Are `Company` and `Role` value types or complex objects (in which case it wont work - you cant bind to a complex object). And are `Companies` and `Roles` typeof `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`? If you wont post your model and controller, no one can guess!

Comment: @StephenMuecke `Company` and `Role` are classes that represent separate tables in the database to which users are linked. `Companies` and `Roles` are of type `List<SelectListItem>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've also added in the user model and a little bit more "behind the scenes" so as to expose all the properties and give a decent picture (I think) of how the user looks at the end of the day. Please see Edit 2

Comment: As per my last comment, you **cant** bind to a complex object. Ideally you should be using a view model with (say) `public int SelectedCompany { get; set; }` but you could (not recommended) use `@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.Company.ID, Model.Companies)` so long as there are no validation attributes on any other properties of `Company` (since only the `ID` property of `Company` will post back)

Answer (score 0):

I always use the "for" helper in this situation

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedCompany, Model.Companies)
```

to pre set the selected you just need to set "selectedCompany" on the controller

```
model.selectedCompany = //the users previous selection
```

this will also tie the selection made by the user to your model so if the drop down is changed, the value of selectedCompany will be set to what it was changed to on the view.